# About Java Swing Focus not swifting to from button to panel

Tags: java, swing, focuslistener

So I have a JFrame with a lot of JPanels and a JButton in it.

I set up the `FocusListener` for the panels that when `FocusGained` it changes color to yellow, when `FocusLost` it changes back to white.

When I clicked the Button the focus goes to the Button; is there any way to keep the focus on the panel while I click the button?

Thank you!!!

Comment: So the panel won't change back to white when I clicked the button.

Comment: when you click a button focuslost from panel.what are you trying to do?do you want to keep color yellow in panel?

Comment: `JPanel` is not focusable by default, so the only the button is actually focusable. *"s there any way to keep the focus on the panel while i click the button?"* - You could request focus back when it's lost, but that's a real pain to the user, alternatively, you could make the button non-focusable

Comment: Yes, when I click the button I want to the panel to remain yellow

Comment: So I do not have the access to the JButton actually, are there any other ways to do it?

Comment: if you want it to remaining yellow why did you add focuslost event?

Comment: Because there are a lot of panels and I only want one of these to be yellow, the others are white. So when i click another panel i need the focusLost to change the former panel back to white. I want the one to remain yellow when I click the button.

Comment: when you click on a jpanel focus will not gain to clicked one.did you write code to gain focus when you click a jpanel.[mouse listener-request focus()]?

Comment: Yes I did. requestFocusInWindow()

Comment: @Preston can you post your code in pastebin .i stll think you have alternative ways to do that